# AWS Beanstalk drive full?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application running on a multi-region AWS Beanstalk environment (.Net in Windows). It has been running for years, and I initially gave it 30GB drive space.

The other day errors started appearing while using the application, and they specified that there was no drive space left.

After increasing to 50GB it started running smoothly again.

My question is this, what could it be that has eaten up 30GB of space? Logs? I can't think of anything else. The application is only 80 MB in size. Is there any way to purge the drive of logs using the AWS Dashboard?

Comment: You could login to the instance and take a look. Alternatively, if it is using Auto Scaling, you could terminate the instance and have Elastic Beanstalk launch a replacement instance. But, frankly, if it is working okay now you could just leave it be. The extra 20GB is probably only costing you $2/month.

Comment: Been having issues logging in, will try again. Yeah the 2 bucks isn’t a problem, just curious what it might be taking up all that space.